# How would I tweet a video link from iOS App which look like twitter site?

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I am using TwitterKit framework for login with Twitter and getting user details. That part of my App is done. Now, I want to tweet a video link from my iOS App.

Here is the story:

- User signs up using Twitter in our server.
- User take a video from his/her iPhone. We upload that video to Amazon.
- User wants to share this video to Twitter (Tweet that video link).

How would I achieve that. My question is not focused on just how to upload a video link. A tweet made by user should look like this:

---

### [image]

The image has been taken from [here](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/rest-api-now-supports-native-video-upload) which explains that you will have to upload video to twitter. Will I have to upload a video to Twitter to get such a view ? Do I have any other alternative to make focus on the tweet that it's a video link?

Also, I came to know that I can do that somehow using `Twitter card`. Exploring for that. If anyone have idea about `Twitter card`, please post an answer.

Comment: Did you find out how to accomplish it?

Comment: See my edit..I had found something later